# Windows Azure Cache Session State Wrong Values

Tags: c#, iis, azure

I have a cloud based application using Windows Azure Cache Service. Here are my settings:

```
<!-- Windows Azure Caching session state provider -->
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AFCacheSessionStateProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="AFCacheSessionStateProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" cacheName="default" dataCacheClientName="default" applicationName="AFCacheSessionState"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>


  <dataCacheClients>
<dataCacheClient name="default">
  <!--To use the in-role flavor of Windows Azure Caching, set identifier to be the cache cluster role name -->
  <!--To use the Windows Azure Caching Service, set identifier to be the endpoint of the cache cluster -->
  <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="xyz.cache.windows.net" />
  <!--<localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" objectCount="100000" ttlValue="300" />-->
  <!--Use this section to specify security settings for connecting to your cache. This section is not required if your cache is hosted on a role that is a part of your cloud service. -->
  <securityProperties mode="Message" sslEnabled="true">
    <messageSecurity authorizationInfo="xxx" />
  </securityProperties>
</dataCacheClient>
```

My session variables are getting mixed up between customers, which happened after I added this session state management. Here is what's happening:

1. Customer goes to page A. Email is joe@123.com. A variable called email is held in session state.
2. User navigates to page 2. The variable changes to jack@456.com. At no time is the variable assigned by other code. It stays constant. It seems my session state management is mixing up my variables.

Could this be caused by incorrect settings or code? I am only using a small VM with one core. Should I use another session state management?

Comment: Showing session state portion of config and your code could help in diagnosing problem.

Comment: The one you've added is commented out... If it is not commented out in actual config file than it looks ok. See if requests are actually have correct cookies (i.e. use Fiddler) - maybe something wrong with session IDs?

Comment: I believe the Windows Azure Cache Service is on beta? Could this be a bug? This issue happens once in a while and it is hard to find.

Comment: Did you find the cause of this? We're having the exact same problem.